# Refactoring nested array comparison iterators (loops)

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, web, iterator

Can anyone point me in the right direction on whether I am iterating over two arrays correctly. Is there any other ways to compose my code without nesting the iterators?

The code below iterates over two object arrays comparing values using the underscore library. I originally wrote the these using nested for loops.

Again I'm not asking for a direct answer, I'm self taught and I sometimes feel like do things completely opposite to how they should be done.

```
function getFilesAdded( directoryData ) {
    return new Promise(function( resolve, reject ) {
        _.each(liveDirectories, function( liveDirectory ) {
            _.each(directoryData, function( directory ) {
                if ( directory.DirectoryName === liveDirectory.DirectoryName && directory.Files.length > liveDirectory.NumOfFiles ) {
                    var filesAdded = [];
                    numOfFilesAdded = directory.Files.length - liveDirectory.NumOfFiles;
                    fileArray = orderByTimeAdded(directory.Files, directory.DirectoryName);
                    fileArray.slice(0, numOfFilesAdded).forEach(pushToArray(filesAdded))
                    liveDirectory.NumOfFiles = directory.Files.length;
                    filesAddedCount === 0 ? (filesAddedCount++, reject()) : (resolve(_.sortBy(filesAdded, 'FileName')));
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

**liveDirectories**

```
[ 
    { 
       DirectoryName: './zaf/betting', 
       NumOfFiles: 5 
    },
    { 
       DirectoryName: './zaf/racecard', 
       NumOfFiles: 5 
    } 
]
```

**directoryData**

```
[ 
    { 
        DirectoryName: './zaf/betting',
        Files:
         [ 'b1.txt',
           'b2.txt',
           'b3.txt',
           'b4.txt',
           'betting_files_here.txt' ] 
    },
    { 
        DirectoryName: './zaf/racecard',
        Files:
         [ 'r1.txt',
           'r2.txt',
           'r3.txt',
           'r4.txt',
           'racecard_files_here.txt' ] 
    }
```

]

Comment: show the data you're iterating over

Comment: @Maximus added above.

Comment: so what is your question re the data your shown?

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is an alternative two nesting a loop within a loop / _.each within a _.each? Or am I doing it the practical way already?

Comment: I'd iterate over the livedirectories once and store them in an object with the directory name as key. That way you can iterate over the directory data and easily lookup the live directory using the directory name, i.e. use a lookup map

Comment: It would be more convenient to match corresponding folders if you used objects with directory name as a key, instead of arrays.

Comment: Okay, that sounds brilliant thank you for the advice. It's really appreciated.

Comment: There is an easy way to compare iterable elements in JavaScript. You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) . Refer [this](http://www.javascripture.com/Map) for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code based on advice given**

Thanks for the help everyone.

```
function iterateAddedFiles( numOfFilesAdded, fileArray, filesAdded ) {
    fileArray.slice(0, numOfFilesAdded).forEach(pushToArray(filesAdded))
}

function getFilesAdded( directoryData ) {
    return new Promise(function( resolve, reject ) {
        var dirMap = new Map()
        _.each(liveDirectories, function( liveDirectory ) {
            dirMap.set(liveDirectory.DirectoryName, liveDirectory)
        })
        _.each(directoryData, function( directory ) {
            var liveDir = dirMap.get(directory.DirectoryName)
            if ( directory.Files.length > liveDir.NumOfFiles && count > 0) {
                var fileArray = [];
                filesAdded = [];
                numOfFilesAdded = directory.Files.length - liveDir.NumOfFiles
                fileArray = orderByTimeAdded(directory.Files, directory.DirectoryName);
                iterateFiles(numOfFilesAdded, fileArray, filesAdded)
                liveDir.NumOfFiles = directory.Files.length;
                count++
                resolve(_.sortBy(filesAdded, 'FileName'))
            } else {
                count++
            }
        })
    })
}
```